# Should dimension tables ever be larger than fact tables?

Tags: star-schema

I have a star schema (it was given to me).  In this schema, a particular fact table has about 5 million records where it's relative dimension table has about 14 million records.

I am much more familiar with normalized data sets so this is something that confuses me.  Is this a red flag or might I be missing something?

Here, let me add an illustration.  Lets say we were tracking dogs and dog bowls

```
Fact_Dog

Fido,  Malamute, Dog_Bowl_1
Buster, Corgi, Dog_Bowl_2

Dim_DogBowl

Dog_Bowl_1, Cheap Dog Food, Week 1
Dog_Bowl_1, Better Dog Food, Week 2
Dog_Bowl_1, Average Dog Food, Week 3
Dog_Bowl_2, Wet Dog Food, Week 1
Dog_Bowl_2, Super good food, Week2
```

Something like this is what I am dealing with. obviously the Dim_DogBowl table has either an external primary key or a combined key of Dog Bowl number and Week number.

Something tells me that this isn't really a star schema even though the names indicate it is.

Comment: I there are 14 million dimension rows and 5 million fact rows, then there are at least 9 million **unused** dimension rows. What for?

Comment: That's an excellent question, I wish i knew

Comment: sorry i take it back... I guess i do know.  So.  the dimension table has perhaps 20 records for every thing it represents.  Each record has a date range on it and only some of those date ranges (possibly more than one) is current.

Comment: If the dimension records have start and end dates then it’s probably a slowly changing dimension (SCD2)

Comment: Ah very interesting,  I have not heard of that before and I believe you are correct.  in my case the dimensions change rarely, but they do change over the course of weeks/years